# with sqlplus, how do i run an explain plan on a query in a file

Tags: oracle11g, sqlplus

generally, i can run a .sql file in windows like so:

```
SQL> @"longpath/sqlfile.sql"
```

and sqlplus will spit out the results of the query.

but i'm trying to run something like:

```
SQL> EXPLAIN PLAN FOR @"longpath/sqlfile.sql";
```

i'm getting an error

```
EXPLAIN PLAN FOR @"longpath/sqlfile.sql"
                 *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00905: missing keyword
```

not sure what keyword im missing...

Comment: no you can't do that.  EXPLAIN PLAN is a SQL statement so you need to put it in the file